# Is there an option to specify sequential for NSEnumerationOptions?

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, enumeration

Currently I am using concurrent enumeration of array using

```
[arr enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) { ... }];
```

Is there a way to specify that the block needs to be enumerated in sequence? I am looking for something like:

```
NSEnumerationOptions opts = isConcurrent ? NSEnumerationConcurrent : <how-to-specify-sequential>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `0` for "no options". Since the default is to enumerate sequentially, this will give you the desired result.

```
NSEnumerationOptions opts = isConcurrent ? NSEnumerationConcurrent : 0;
```